# Uniqueness of solution in $x' = 5\text{cos}^2(tx)-x^2-5$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

Given the initial value problem $$\begin{cases} x' = 5\text{cos}^2(tx)-x^2-5 \\ x(1)=0\end{cases}$$

I am asked to prove that it has a unique solution for the given initial condition ($x(1)=0)$

I have tried to prove it seeing that $f(t,x) = 5\text{cos}^2(tx)-x^2-5$ is Lipschitz-continuous. Using the intermediate value theorem I got that $$|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|<(10t+|x+y|)|x-y|$$
However I still have not used the fact that $x(1)=0$ at any point, how does knowing that help me prove the uniqueness of solution?

Comment: What formulations for uniqueness do you know? One rather general is that if the right side is smooth (at least once cont. differentiable), every solution is unique as long as it exists. Which is trivially true for this ODE.